# Generating DDL from EDMX programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ddl, edmx

I want to create a deployment page in my web application.
I would also like to use the same method to create an upgrade page for the database.
I use the following code to generate the DDL sql scripts for the EDMX file i have.

```
IObjectContextAdapter context = new ApplicationDBContext();
var sqlScript = context.ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

this generates a creation script for the entire database.

I would like it to create a DDL script that will use `IF EXSISTS` and `DROP` `CREATE` decleartion to reset the existing database.

is it possible ?

I would also like to have a toggle that will upgrade the current database only adding the new fields and tables that does not exist.

is it also possible ?

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx) `context.Database` property. You will find a lot of useful methods in it. You basically can check if database exists, drop, create database, check if it is compatible with your model.

Also [consider](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) Entity Framework Migrations. This is a modern way to handle database changes.